# Code Igniter cookies need to be cleared in order to log in

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I will start by saying I did not write the code, I inherited it, and I am new to CI on this project. Please let me know if you need further info to help.

Can anyone offer any insight as to why sometimes login doesn't work (just redirects to the login page again with no error) or adding an item to a cart on the site doesn't work (it just doesn't go into the cart) until I clear my cookies?

I clear my cookies and the log in works and I can add items to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is corrupting (writing bad data) in your session storage (for the chart) and corrupting cookie too.

Please review where is your code altering session storage (maybe in some javascript library) and cookie for login (check your login controller php file on CI).

Comment: What would "bad data" look like? Nothing looks wrong on first glance. One thing I didn't mention is that sometimes I don't have to clear my cookies. Sometimes it works fine.

Comment: So, please review code files where you're changing cookies values. It seems to be a problem in your logic when you get this information. Anyway, please expand your question with some example in order that more users can understand the situation. Thanks.

Comment: If you are asking for an example of what is in my user_data of my session, this is it: